# Switching between multiple CSS files using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to make a series of buttons that the user of my site can click on in order to change between different CSS3 files, which will change certain effects.  In order to accomplish this goal, I need some way of accessing the

```
href="example1.css"
```

tag in my HTML, and changing it to

```
href="example2.css"
```

using JavaScript or HTML.

Comment: You can do this two ways: using vanilla js, or jquery.  This question was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522545/how-to-change-the-css-stylesheet-dynamically-for-a-website-being-viewed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assign an `id` to your link. Fetch it in JS by its `id` and change the `href` attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example1.css" id="lnk"/>
```

In JS:

```
var link = document.getElementsById("lnk"); //Fetch the link by its ID
link.setAttribute("href", "example2.css"); //Change its href attribute
```

You can also do it without an `id`.

```
document.querySelector("link[href='example1.css']").href = "example2.css";
```

Comment: Spelling mistake. `getElementsById` should be `getElementById` since really, the `Id` should be unique, and hence there should be only one of it.

Answer (score 0):

not

```
var link = document.getElementsById("lnk"); //Fetch the link by its ID
```

but

```
link = document.getElementById("lnk");
```

The ID is ONE, getElementsById - is array