# Is it possible to set a class in the class in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a dark theme for my site and it works on the principle that when a button is clicked, a javascript code automatically adds a `DARK` class to the `body` tag. How can I make it so that the `H1` tag has a white color when the body has a `DARK` class, and a gray color when there's no `DARK` class on the `body` tag?

Comment: I'm going to assume that English is a second a language? Your question at the minute doesn't really make sense. Can you add some code to help explain what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your question is poorly worded, I think I understand what you are trying to do.

If I understand correctly, you want your `H1` tag to have a white color if the `BODY` tag has a `dark` class added to it, and gray color if there's no `dark` class.

This is pretty easy to achieve with CSS, so I'll just give an example that will help you understand this.

In your CSS file (if you use a separate stylesheet file) or `style` tag, add a `body > h1` style like so:

```
body > h1{
  color: gray;
}
```

The above styling changes the default `H1` tag color to gray when the site loads. To have toe color change automatically when you programatically add a `dark` class to the site's body tag, add the following style (immediately below the above one preferably):

```
body.dark > h1{
  color: white;
}
```

The style above changes the `H1` tag color to white if there's a dark class on the `BODY` tag.

In summary, your site style should look something like below to achieve your specific request:

```
body > h1{
  color: gray;
}

body.dark > h1{
  color: white;
}
```

You should really study more on CSS as this is really not difficult to achieve with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 stylesheets, 1 default and the other dark. Then look at [Switching between multiple CSS files using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401880/switching-between-multiple-css-files-using-javascript) for changing the stylesheet on the fly. 
You will also need to store the users selecting within a cookie then retrieve the value and use the same code to change the stylesheet (otherwise the user needs to select the option for each page that they visit).