# How to apply themes to Bootstrap Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded Bootstrap html template. I want to change colors based on user interest.So I want to apply themes to template. How to apply themes.
please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the theme. You would have got the css file. So for changing the theme you just have to replace the new theme CSS file with old one. Or better you store the CSS files in a different folder and point your application there.

Be careful about the bootstrap version. It should be matched with the existing one.

Comment: Check this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745565/switching-between-twitter-bootstrap-themes