# jQuery Mobile: data_icon images issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm using `ASP.NET MVC 4` with `jQuery mobile` to display a web application on an android smartphone.

I updated from `jQuery mobile 1.1.0` to `1.3.1` and everything seemed to port across properly except for my data icons. When I'm debugging locally through a browser they are displayed correctly but when I test it on my android device the icons aren't correct.

It almost seems like the icon there but isn't positioned correct, eg. where the "gear" icon should be, it looks like half of a "down arrow" icon is showing.

My css files are in `~/Content/` and my images files are in `~/Content/images`.

I have tried replaces the updated (`1.3.0`) images with the images that come with `1.1.0` and `1.2.1` and none seem to work.

[image: Android] [image: Browser]
Here is what is looks like on the android and in the browser respectively.

Any ideas why this would be happening or how to fix this?

Comment: are you using your own theme, built with Theme roller? if not, you dont need to load structure at all. load only jqm-theme.css and jqm.js

Comment: Having the same difficulty here. Working on iPods IOS 6.1.3, JQ 1.9.1 and JQM 1.3.1. Some icons are missing the image, on others the image is not centered in the circular window(similar to above). Using default data-theme="c".

Comment: I deleted all the jQuery and jQuery-mobile files from my scripts/contents folder (moved to a different location) and re-downloaded jQuery 1.9, jQuery migrate and jQuery-mobile 1.3.1 again, put the new files in the content and scripts area and it worked. Honestly I don't know why it worked but it hasn't happened since.

Comment: Try reloading the css with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13721261/1096200

Answer (score 1):

It seems to just be a bug with jQuery mobile 1.3.1.

I replaced the structure and theme css files with the 1.2.1 alternatives and they now display correctly.

**EDIT:**

Going through my app again today and they've reverted back to displaying incorrectly.. without changing anything.. :/