# Reload CSS without refreshing entire page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, updatepanel

I have a page that is on a 60 timer. The following piece of code does this on tick:

```
protected void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportRepeater.DataBind();
        ReportUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

This web app will be placed in a "kiosk" mode on a tablet and will only be used for viewing that web app. If I make a change to CSS and publish it to the server, I have to explicitly refresh the page before the style changes take effect. Just updating the `UpdatePanel` isn't good enough. Is there some way in the code above I can tell it to go get that or should I maybe use another timer that every *x* number of minutes/hours it does a complete page reload? I tried some googling but came up short - likely because this I already have the only viable solution or this is a rare situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload CSS stylesheets with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721183/reload-css-stylesheets-with-javascript)

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13721183/81053

Answer (score 0):

1) Provide a source (service, view, etc.) of yielding the new CSS from the server.

2) Use javascript on the clientside ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/how-do-i-switch-my-css-stylesheet-using-jquery)) to load the CSS from the service. Use a client-side javascript timer to perform the requests.

EDIT: I just remembered that you might get a `303` error if the CSS URL isn't changing. Consult [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721183/reload-css-stylesheets-with-javascript) example if that's an issue. Also - the commenters beat me to it with that source (although I legitimately dug that one ;))