# Apply CSS file to a certain div

Tags: css

I have a site.css and something similar to mobile.css.
What I am building is a webpage where you can preview the app you've made. Imagine it like a site devided in half where one half has a panel with controls while the other one has the preview (div), curently designed as a mobile phone.

So what I am actually doing is a mobile phone on my site (preview), but the problem is that I dont know how to use the mobile.css file in the preview div only.

Is there a way to import a CSS file for one div (and its children)?

A simplified look of my page: https://jsfiddle.net/kc8rgde2/1/

`<iframe>`, `<style scoped>` or external CSS preprocesors are not an option.

EDIT:
I kinda decided to go with SASS as it was the easiest to understand and Visual Studio had a nice extension for it.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: For your question, and the requirements you have, I doubt there are any right answer...

Comment: How about re-loading CSS through jQuery? Make the selectors specific for `#preview-mobile` in that CSS, and (re-)load that on changes.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to do that?

Comment: Why can't you use  iFrame, <Style scoped> or external CSS preprocesors ? i assume you also cannot use `object`

Comment: iFrame - huge amount of problems with my models and angular
Style scoped - not supported on most browsers
CSS preprocesors - not my project so i am not really allowed to install anything

Comment: @Hopless http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024486/is-there-an-easy-way-to-reload-css-without-reloading-the-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721183/reload-css-stylesheets-with-javascript http://nv.github.io/css_auto-reload/

Comment: Flagged there is no possible answer to this question based on your specification.

Comment: Well thats no what i am looking for. What I need is to apply the CSS from the mobile CSS file (mobile.css) to the phone, what you suggested is more like refreshing the content (which i am doing with angularJS)

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea. It could work, and it needs a lot of testing.Check this fiddle ->
https://jsfiddle.net/kc8rgde2/2/

Basically, as you can see, in the fiddle there's no bootstrap loaded.
I load bootstrap, and access the file using the CDN link from an AJAX request.

The response of the ajax, is the content of the bootstrap css file (minified version) - (check the console!)

What i do after, is replacing all the classes (dots) with ("#phonePreview .") and this prepends the phone preview div id to all the classes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $.when($.get("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"))
  .done(function(response) {
    var res = response.replace(/\./g,'#phonePreview .')
    console.debug (res);
    $('<style />').text(res).appendTo($('body'))
});
})
```

Prepending the parent id means that the classes are applied only to #phonePreview children.

It's just a starting point, but with some work it could work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use styles specifically for devices under a certain size you could use media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 431px) {

.myDiv {
style: style;
style: style;
}

#div2 {
style: style;
style: style;
}

}
```

`max-width: 431px` means devices that are 431px or lower in width. You could also use height and change it to `min-width`.

Comment: Well this is not the right answer as my mobile device would be displayed on a normal display and not a mobile one.

But I already did what i wanted to do with a CSS preprocessor (which i didnt really want, but as long as it works so awesomely i have no problem :D)