# Programatically reload CSS files with Selenium or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

I'm currently working on a tiny Sublime Text plugin that involves controlling a Chrome instance with Selenium. One of the features I'm working on is live reloading of styles. The idea is to reload the CSS on the browser (through Selenium) any time you make a change on any of your CSS files.

I can easily reload the browser, but I don't want to do that, because its rather slow, and maybe you have some input on the page, which would be lost. Ideally I would like to force Chrome to reload all styles without reloading the page. Since I can inject JavaScript code into Chrome with Selenium, it suffices an answer using JavaScript only, I can deal with the Selenium part. However, if there is some Selenium-specific way of doing this, even better!

I would rather not depend on jQuery or any other external libraries for this, but if needed, I can live with that also.

For the time being, I don't need compatibility with any other browser than Chrome (>31), but if there is a cross-browser compatible solution, it would be a plus!

**EDIT**: After reading a few answers to similar questions, I want to add a few constrains:

- I'm not writing the HTML, so I cannot change the way styleheets are added, or the order, neither can I expect them to have a specific id, or anything like that. I can inject any JavaScipt I want, but I cannot control how the HTML was generated in the first place.
- I don't want to append `?v=random()` or anything like that, because I don't have control over the server either, so I don't know if the server will look at that and do something different. Besides, I would not like to circumvent the caching, if the server responds `302` and the browser caches, then I'm OK with that.
- If possible, I would like the solution to work also for programatically injected CSS (as far as is possible), since the page may be using some CSS AMD loader, or any other Ajax stuff. Ideally, I would like to say to Chrome "please reapply all CSS" as abstract as possible, instead of relying on finding all `link` tags and such, because those solutions always have a gotcha.

Just to clarify, I know these are kind of hard constrains, but I'm developing a plugin for a text editor, so I need to cope with every technology/web framework/methodology the developer is using, so I cannot trust too much that the developer will follow certain patterns. Of course, I would like to cope with as many situations as possible, but I'm willing to drop unrealistic constrains if necessary. However, I do can force developers to use a specific version of Chrome, at least for developing.

As of now, none of the answers I've found on SO so far provide this level of development-agnosticism.

Comment: this might be hlepful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024486/is-there-an-easy-way-to-reload-css-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Thanks @CodeMonk, I had already seen it. Unfortunately it involves changing the `innerHtml`, and so requires to have CSS embedded in the document. As I said, I cannot rely on any specific structure for the document, nor can I put anything on the server. The others answers fail to comply other constrains I added. Thanks anyway for the interest.