# How to change the css file and scripts on the master page without the post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to change the css and script tags file of header part of master page without the post back.
I have a tab control on the aspx page, when changing each tab then scripts tag on the master page should change wrt to that tabs without post back. How can I do that?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024486/is-there-an-easy-way-to-reload-css-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: yes but all the css and scripts are package of sencha ext js..example
Just make the two dialogs one in 3.x and other in 4.x want to change the 3.x to 4.x and 4.x to 3.x by change the tabs without post back

Comment: Well that's general approach applies to every library. If that not gonna work for you than try update your question to have more detail about exact problem with ext if any.