# How to reload or rerender CSS for a single HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a `div.foo` with this CSS:

```
.foo {
    height: 70vh;
}
```

And I change the height of `div.foo` with jQuery like this:

```
$('.foo').height(100);
```

How do I reset the CSS of `div.foo` so its height is rendered `70vh` again?

One solution that works is to reload the entire CSS file [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2024618/1612318). But I wonder if there is a solution to only reset the CSS of `div.foo`, not the entire stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery, you are adding your styles to the `style` attribute of the element. It is removed again, if you call the function again with an empty string (`""`). This will remove the property in the `style` attribute.

If you have e.g. this command:

```
$('.foo').css('height', '100px');
```

You can revoke it by

```
$('.foo').css('height', '');
```

See also the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036868/3233827

Answer (score 3):

`$('.foo).height('');` should be sufficient to erase the style applied by jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `style` attribute from the element. This attribute holds any dynamic styles.

```js
$('.foo').css('background', 'teal');

$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('.foo').removeAttr('style');
});
```

```css
.foo {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo"></div>
<p><button id="reset">Reset style</button></p>
```

Comment: This will remove every style property of this element, not only one single property.

Comment: What if there are inline styles that he doesn't want removed?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 That's what the OP asked