# How can I revert the page to original after I've clicked a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this Arabic to English buttons that changes the entire page to Arbic format and vice versa using a function that targets every element.

The page starts in Arabic format and when the english btn is pressed this function is performed :

```
function englishPage()
{
    document.getElementById('taskForm').style.gap = '6px'
    document.querySelector('.title').style.padding = '0 6px'
    document.getElementById('taskinput').setAttribute('placeholder','Have Any New Tasks ?')
    document.getElementById('taskinput').style.fontFamily = "Shantell Sans"
    document.getElementById('tsk-sub-btn').setAttribute('value','Add')
    document.getElementById('tsk-sub-btn').style.fontFamily = "Shantell Sans"
    document.getElementById('tsk-arc-btn').setAttribute('value','Archive')
    document.getElementById('tsk-arc-btn').style.fontFamily = "Shantell Sans"
    document.getElementById('navele1').innerHTML = "Tasks"
    document.getElementById('navele1').style.fontFamily = "Shantell Sans"
    document.getElementById('navele2').innerHTML = "Archived Tasks"
    document.getElementById('navele2').style.fontFamily = "Shantell Sans"
}
```

But I want when i press the Arabic button back the page reverts to its original form.

I have tried reverting everything in the way I did it to the english Format.
But that takes too much time.

Is there a way to do it easier ?

Comment: See this on how to reload CSS without reloading the page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024486/10875738. You could even have two seperate CSS fils with this, one english/latin and one arabic.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify switching between Arabic and English formats:

- Store original styles and attributes in an object.
- Create functions to apply English styles and attributes, and revert to original styles and attributes.
- Add event listeners to toggle between these functions when the corresponding buttons are clicked.

Below is the sample code in JS to do it:

```
// Store the original styles and attributes
const originalStyles = {
    taskFormGap: document.getElementById('taskForm').style.gap,
    titlePadding: document.querySelector('.title').style.padding,
    taskInputPlaceholder: document.getElementById('taskinput').getAttribute('placeholder'),
    taskInputFontFamily: document.getElementById('taskinput').style.fontFamily,
    // ... add other original styles and attributes here
};

// Apply the English styles and attributes
function englishPage() {
    // ... your existing englishPage() function code
}

// Revert to the original styles and attributes
function arabicPage() {
    document.getElementById('taskForm').style.gap = originalStyles.taskFormGap;
    document.querySelector('.title').style.padding = originalStyles.titlePadding;
    document.getElementById('taskinput').setAttribute('placeholder', originalStyles.taskInputPlaceholder);
    document.getElementById('taskinput').style.fontFamily = originalStyles.taskInputFontFamily;
    // ... revert other styles and attributes here
}

// Event listener for the buttons
document.getElementById('englishBtn').addEventListener('click', englishPage);
document.getElementById('arabicBtn').addEventListener('click', arabicPage);
```